# Pick variable depending on condition

Tags: python, variables, ansible, jinja2

I have the following variable:

```
secureVar:
  cosmosconstr: ""
  postgresUrl: ""
```

which can be either empty or contain database urls, depending on that i need to conditionally create external services in kubernetes:

```
- name: Get DB data
  when: (secureVars | from_json)['cosmosconstr'] | length == 0 and (secureVars | from_json)['postgresUrl'] | length == 0
  shell: ./python/db_credentials.py -dp {{ deploymentPrefix }}
  register: dbData

- name: Generate external services templates
  when: (secureVars | from_json)['cosmosconstr'] | length == 0 and (secureVars | from_json)['postgresUrl'] | length == 0
  action: template src=k8s/common/external-services.j2 dest=/tmp/k8s-external-svc.yml
  vars:
    cosmosUrl: "{{ dbData.stdout_lines[0] | urlsplit('hostname') }}"
    postgresUrl: "{{ dbData.stdout_lines[1] }}"

- name: Generate external services templates
  when: (secureVars | from_json)['cosmosconstr'] | length > 0 and (secureVars | from_json)['postgresUrl'] | length > 0
  action: template src=k8s/common/external-services.j2 dest=/tmp/k8s-external-svc.yml
  vars:
    cosmosUrl: "{{ ( secureVars | from_json )['cosmosconstr'] | urlsplit('hostname') }}"
    postgresUrl: "{{ ( secureVars | from_json )['postgresUrl'] }}"
```

this is what I'm doing right now, I'd like to set a condition so that if the dbData is skipped I would use `secureVars` and if its not skipped I'd use dbData, the problem is, I cant check if `dbData.skipped` equals true, because if its not skipped, it doesnt contain `skipped` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use default False value.

> when: dbData.skipped | default('False')

edit from the OP:

I ended up doing this:

```
"{% if dbData.skipped is defined %}{{ ( secureVars.stdout | from_json )['postgresUrl'] }}{% else %}{{ dbData.stdout_lines[1] }}{% endif %}"
```

Comment: the problem is, i cant have this logic on the task level (because I want to merge 2 tasks into 1 that always runs), it needs to be inside the task, will that work?

Comment: Sure it will, whatever.

Comment: okay, let me try it (probably tomorrow) and get back to you, thanks!